# Duplicati uses symmetric encryption despite giving the recipient ID_key

Tags: encryption, gnupg, public-key-encryption

I have a question regarding decrypt using gpg asymmetrically. I use duplicity encrypt copies asymmetrically.

E.g:

```
 `Duplicati.CommandLine.exe backup s3://testduplicatigpg3 C:\Users\test\Desktop\tt --aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --encryption-module=gpg --gpg-encryption-command="--encrypt" --passphrase=test --gpg-encryption-switches="-r ID_KEY"`
```

And I restore using:

```
  Duplicati.CommandLine.exe restore s3://testduplicatigpg3 --restore-path=C:\Users\test\Desktop\restore --aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --encryption-module=gpg --gpg-decryption-command="--decrypt" --passphrase=test
```

Can I somehow force the Duplicity requirements of the private key and password to restore files. For example, using the gpg, after removing the private key I can't decrypted files.

I conclude that despite the duplicity encrypts all my files symmetrically. Although I want to have the option of asymmetric encryption.

Would anyone be able to provide a valid example of the use of asymmetric encryption in Duplicati?

Comment: If you can no longer decrypt after removing the private key, I would take this as an indication that `duplicati` indeed uses asymmetric encryption. Can you explain how you came to the opposing conclusion?

Comment: In my experience, after removing gpg key, Duplicati STILL DECRYPTS, which is VERY BAD. Either it doesn't encrypt asymmetrically, or it stores the private key! Neither it asks for the passphrase... it's very strange. Maybe this is what kisiel is trying to ask?

Comment: For further info, see [this issue](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/2270#issuecomment-431554427)